# JAX scan efficient in backprop without TensorArray?

Tags: jax

TF provides the `TensorArray` to make automatic iteration and stacking efficient in `scan` or `while_loop`.

The naive variant with gathering and concatenating or dynamic updates would be inefficient with backprop, because backprop would keep copies of the full array in each iteration. E.g. assume you are collecting `ys` of shape [T,B,F], and iterating over t in [0,...,T-1]. Now two possible naive variants:

1. You don't know T in advance. You allocate the initial `ys` tensor of shape [0,B,F], and each iteration, you concatenate a new vector [B,F], extended as [1,B,F] to it, so in each step t, the current `ys` is of shape [t,B,F].
2. You know T in advance. You can allocate the initial `ys` tensor of shape [T,B,F]. In each iteration, you update `ys[t]` (e.g. `tensor_scatter_nd_update`).

I have seen the concat variant being used for self-attention implementations.

I was checking JAX while_loop and scan and it seems it does not have `TensorArray` but instead uses `dynamic_index_in_dim`/`dynamic_slice` and `dynamic_update_index_in_dim`/`dynamic_update_slice` (like `tensor_scatter_nd_update`), which is like variant 2.

Without considering backprop, variant 2 can be efficient if it would update inplace, actually more so than `TensorArray`. But if it does not update inplace for some reason, you get O(T^2) runtime. Variant 1 would also likely lead to O(T^2) runtime, unless it can be very clever and having preallocated a tensor which is bigger. Then it might get away with O(T log T) runtime, similar to C++ `std::vector`. But I very much doubt that.

When considering backprop, it is much worse, unless there are some clever optimizations happening. But for the standard case, it would need to store a copy of the full `ys` tensor in every iteration, for the use of backprop. So it means you get T times a copy of `ys`. This means O(T^2) memory consumption.

With TF `TensorArray`, this is not the case, as each tensor `ys[t]` is treated separately. It is efficient and only has O(T) runtime and memory consumption, even with backprop.

So, my question is: Is JAX `scan` really inefficient like I described, esp for the case of backprop? Or if not, why not? How does it avoid the O(T^2) memory consumption in backprop? Is this some automatic optimization? How does it work?

---

I was implementing [some script](https://github.com/albertz/playground/blob/master/jax-naive-scan.py) to test this, and then measuring memory and runtime, for different sequence lengths n. I get this:
[image: mem, runtime]

So, it seems the memory consumption is actual linear, but the runtime seems quadratic.

---

Somewhat related question in [JAX #3106 on TensorArray equivalent](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/3106), but it doesn't really answer my question here on efficiency.

The same question in [JAX #15906](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/15906) with some answers.